# SQL Server Management Studio. Update T1 set T1.Field1 = y where T1.Field1= x Would this work?

Tags: sql, syntax, sql-update, ssms

```
Update T1 set T1.Field1 = y where T1.Field1 = x
```

Would this syntax work?

I want to update the field to equal 40 where that field is currently equal to 50. This would update several rows when run the first time.

I would hope that it would update zero rows when attempting to run it the second time.

Comment: Yes, it should work

Comment: ...and it'll update 0 rows on subsequent executions.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: when is field the correct term?

Comment: Bear in mind that updates affecting 0 rows are still *interesting*. Because e.g. they'll still cause triggers to fire.

Comment: field is an intersection of row and column, if a table has 10 rows and 10 columns then there is 100 fields

Comment: understood. field is not general, but specific. Like exact coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I put this in simple words

```
Update T1 set T1.Field1 = y where T1.Field1 = x

Update T1 set T1.Field1 = 40 where T1.Field1 = 50
```

At first when your table has the value 50 for field1 and all those values will be updated as 40 when you run the update statement.

When you run this second time, now the column Field1 has already been updated as 40 and it's not 50 anymore so nothing will get affected since the update statement only updates 50 as 40.